# Select a weekly booking calendar from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),T.HORAINI_AULA,108) as HORAINI, reservation, day_week
FROM 
   vw_turmas_grade T
```

| HORAINI | reservation | day_week |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19:15 | P1INF.6 | 2 |
| 20:45 | P1INF.6 | 2 |
| 08:15 | PJB2/4 | 2 |
| 09:45 | PJB2/4 | 2 |
| 08:15 | PJB2/4 | 5 |
| 09:45 | PJB2/4 | 5 |
| 11:00 | PJB2/4 | 5 |
| 19:15 | PHC2/4 | 4 |
| 20:45 | PHC2/4 | 4 |
| 19:15 | PHC2/4 | 5 |
| 20:45 | PHC2/4 | 5 |
| 19:15 | PHC2/4 | 2 |
| 20:45 | PHC2/4 | 2 |
| 19:15 | PHC2/4 | 3 |
| 20:45 | PHC2/4 | 3 |
| 19:15 | PJB8 | 2 |

that returns the time and day of the week of the reservation and I would like to create a table of the week with these reservations.

notes: day_week 2 = monday, 3 = tuesday and etc...

Some like this:

| HORAINI | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1900-01-01 08:15:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 09:45:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 11:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 13:15:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 14:15:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 14:45:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 15:45:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 19:15:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 20:45:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1900-01-01 22:00:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

**EDIT: Please ignore the date. Booking times are the same every day**

To be honest, I think I'm making some silly mistake. Already tried a LEFT JOIN and CASEs to try this and not worked.

like:

```
WITH Reservation AS 
(SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),T.HORAINI_AULA,108) as HORAINI,
   reservation, 
   day_week
FROM 
   vw_turmas_grade T)

SELECT 
    HORAINI,
    CASE WHEN R.day_week = '2' THEN R.reservation END as 'Monday'
    CASE WHEN R.day_week = '3' THEN R.reservation END as 'Tuesday'
    CASE WHEN R.day_week = '4' THEN R.reservation END as 'Wednesday'
    CASE WHEN R.day_week = '5' THEN R.reservation END as 'Thursday'
    CASE WHEN R.day_week = '6' THEN R.reservation END as 'Friday'
    CASE WHEN R.day_week = '7' THEN R.reservation END as 'Saturday'
FROM Reservation R
```

| HORAINI | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19:15 | P1INF.6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 20:45 | P1INF.6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 19:15 | NULL | NULL | P1INF.7 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 20:45 | NULL | NULL | P1INF.7 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 19:15 | NULL | NULL | NULL | P1INF.7 | NULL | NULL |
| 20:45 | NULL | NULL | NULL | P1INF.7 | NULL | NULL |
| 19:15 | NULL | P1INF.7 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 20:45 | NULL | P1INF.7 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 19:15 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | P1INF.7 | NULL |
| 20:45 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | P1INF.7 | NULL |

But the table is wrong and the times that do not have a reservation do not appear

Comment: Please share your simple data / expected output as text not images so it can be easy to help

Comment: @SelVazi Sorry about that, it's better now?

Comment: This would be easier if your times were evenly disbursed

Comment: You are looking to *pivot* using your dataset, using *conditional aggregation* Your last query is almost there. You just need to wrap the `CASE` expressions in an aggregate function such as `MAX()`, and add `GROUP BY HORAINI` at the end. There are plenty of examples in SO of such query.